# Showing existence of hamiltonian circuit given number of vertices, edges and the minimum degree of each vertex

Tags: graph-theory

There is a connected graph with $8$ vertices and $22$ edges which has no
$HC$ since $22 = \frac{(n − 1)(n − 2)}{2} + 1$ for $n = 8$.

> Is there such a graph if
>   we assume in addition that each vertex has degree at least $2$? Please
>   provide one if it exists, or provide the argument if such graph does not
>   exist.

**Thoughts:** I tried looking at the complements i.e. graphs on $8$ vertices with $6$ edges and the degree of each vertex at most $5$. But I am not 100% sure as to how I should proceed to show that a hamiltonian cycle exists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $G$ has a vertex of degree two or three then by removing it you get a graph on $7$ vertices with at least 19 edges which is at most $2$ edges short from being complete. Then 
 a hamiltonian path could be found in the new graph between two of the neighbours of the deleted vertex which with the deleted vertex will give you a hamiltonian cycle in the original graph.